# PHP T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I am trying to see what is wrong with this it says it is expecting a ']' but i do not see the problem in my mySQL here is the line it says it is messing up on.

```
('$_POST[first_name]','$_POST[last_name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[phone_number]','$_POST[event_name]','$_POST[event_category]','$_POST[event_ description]','$_POST[event_admission]','$_POST[event_amount]',$event_start_date,$event_end_date,'$_POST[event_location]','$_POST[event_family]')";
```

Here is the full code:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO events_main (first_name, last_name, email, phone_number, event_name, event_category, event_description, event_admission, event_amount, event_start_date, event_end_date, event_location, event_family)VALUES('$_POST[first_name]','$_POST[last_name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[phone_number]','$_POST[event_name]','$_POST[event_category]','$_POST[event_description]','$_POST[event_admission]','$_POST[event_amount]','$event_start_date','$event_end_date','$_POST[event_location]','$_POST[event_family]')";
```

Comment: The real problem is that this code will be so very vurnerable to SQL injections!!

Comment: @juergend I am new to SQL what is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: `$_POST[event_ description]` note the space.

Comment: At a minimum, you _MUST_ replace each of these with a variable escaped via `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['whatever'])`

Comment: See [here](http://littlebobbytables.com/)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thank you so much that was the problem!

Comment: @Michael Berkowski not enough information to work with .. to many asumtions ..had to delete

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski So how would I use the escape string?

Comment: @baba do you want me to show you the whole code to add it into my database?

Comment: Required minimum understanding: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: @maxgee yes .. or just use jack solution

Comment: @maxgee See Jack's answer below - a complicated method using array_map(), but does the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you get the error is because of `event_ description`; the space shouldn't be there.

However, you should use something like this to properly escape your data before saving them in the database:

```
$escaped_values = join(',', array_map(function($v) {
    return "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($v) . "'";
}, array(
    $_POST['first_name'],
    $_POST['last_name'],
    $_POST['email'],
    $_POST['phone_number'],
    $_POST['event_name'],
    $_POST['event_category'],
    $_POST['event_description'],
    $_POST['event_admission'],
    $_POST['event_amount'],
    $event_start_date,
    $event_end_date,
    $_POST['event_location'],
    $_POST['event_family'],
)));

$sql = "INSERT INTO .... VALUES ($escaped_values)";
```

It gets even easier with prepared statements, as the escaping is done for you :)

Comment: @deceze seems like it :)

Comment: @deceze .. just curious what you mean by `nonsense code` ???

Comment: @Baba he pointed out to me that `mysqli_real_escape_string` needs to actually receive parameters to work ... and a closing brace was missing at the end.

Comment: @jack .. surprised you are even using `mysql_real_escape_string` you can add `use($link)` to include the connection link

Comment: @Baba Admittedly I had to guess OP was using `mysql_` functions; the `$link` is usually not necessary unless you connect to multiple databases; but yes, I *could* have used it :)

Comment: @Jack good use of array_map anyway +1